# How do I rebuild my software RAID1 array after a drive replacement?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, raid1, fdisk

So I have 1and1 dedicated host with RAID 1 setup. One of the drive went bad, and they had just replaced it with a good one. Now I need to the build, but I'm not sure which drive is the old one, and which one is the new blank one. Please help. Here's the instruction: http://help.1and1.com/servers-c37684/linux-server-c37687/system-recovery-c37690/how-do-i-rebuild-my-software-raid-array-after-a-drive-replacement-a730894.html

As I understand it correctly, I *_think_* my old drive is /dev/sda, which means I should proceed with step 7 as:

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk /dev/sdb
```

Am I correct? Here's my console stuff. Please help and thank you.

```
[root@u16365582 ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x416e0acb

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1         523     4194304   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2             523         784     2097152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda3             784      121602   970470104   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 3 does not end on cylinder boundary.

Disk /dev/md3: 993.8 GB, 993761296384 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 242617504 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/md1: 4294 MB, 4294901760 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 1048560 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-usr: 34.4 GB, 34359738368 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4177 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-var: 871.9 GB, 871878361088 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 105999 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-home: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 522 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

[root@u16365582 ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active raid1 sda1[0]
      4194240 blocks [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 1/1 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

md3 : active raid1 sda3[1]
      970470016 blocks [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 206/232 pages [824KB], 2048KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
[root@u16365582 ~]#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/dev/sda is your "good" drive as reported by `mdstat`. It also is the one with valid partition data on it as reported by `fdisk`.

Copying the partitioning information over to /dev/sdb using sfdisk as proposed by the guide should be safe if you did not use /dev/sdb for anything before where you would need to retain its data. After you've done this (and probably after an additional `partprobe` call) you should be able to `mdadm manage [...] --add [...]` the partitions `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb3` to `md1` and `md3` respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not a huge Linux user, and touching this stuff could potentially wipe out the entire thing, that's why I'm reluctant.

Comment: @aZn137 you *should* have a backup so wiping out the entire thing would not be that much of a problem - except for the work, downtime and annoyance factor resulting from the restore operation that is.

Comment: very good idea! I have the server running the nightly backup of the entire web root dir, but I'd never thought of backing it up before doing the sync. Then again, I shouldn't have to deal with this as often... I hope.